# How to match brackets in matchadd command regular expression?

Tags: regular-expression, colorscheme

I want to highlight `breakpoint()` - including brackets as keywords in Python files.

I have added these two commands to my `.vimrc`:

```
highlight link PyBreakpoint Keyword        
call matchadd("PyBreakpoint", '\<breakpoint\(\)\>')
```

However, only the `breakpoint` word gets matched and highlighted. How could I match the brackets also in order to apply the color to them also?

Comment: I think by default `\(` creates groups. Try `:help pattern`. Also, you might want to use `after/syntax/python.vim` and the syntax machinery; matches are somewhat limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the backslashes from the parens.  This is what works for me.

```
call matchadd("PyBreakpoint", 'breakpoint()')
```

with example file:

```
this
that
breakpoint()
other
another
```

Comment: I have ended up using `call matchadd("PyBreakpoint", '\sbreakpoint()\s')`.